# What bracha do you make on kasha varnishkes?

Tags: blessing, food, ikar-tofel

Assuming that there is an even amount of "varnishkes" (noodles) and kasha, do you make 2 brachot - *mezonot* on the varnishkes and *adamah* on the kasha? (If so, which should you say first?)

Or is this combination considered an *ikkar / tafel* food regardless of the proportions. I.e., it's based on the general recipe / intention of the food. I.e., AFAIK, the kasha is *ikkar /tafel* situation where the kasha is *ikar* and you should say just *ha'adamah*?

(Most recipes of this that I've seen are mainly kasha. Also,, perhaps, the name of the food "kasha varnishkes" suggests the idea that the kasha is the main idea and the varnishkes are added for "decoration" or "filler" or, perhaps, b/c most people don't like just plain kasha.)

Comment: In pretty much all mezonos/non-mezonos _ikkar_ / _tefel_ situations, the _mezonos_ is considered the _ikkar_. The only exception would be if the _mezonos_ food is **purely** to hold the food together

Comment: @Daniel Ah! That last sentence might actually be a possibility with kasha varnishkes. I never thought about it that way.

Comment: No, it's definitely not a possibility in this case. Pasta isn't just to hold the food together.

Comment: @Daniel I get it, now. Mezonot - like matzah meal or flour to thicken the sauce. Too bad about this rule. I was hoping that I would be able to say "hamotzi" on the frozen gefilte fish ;-) (It's now mainly matza meal in some brands, BTW.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When two foods with different brachot are mixed together sufficiently that any bite you take would certainly contain both items, only one bracha is said on the food. Furthermore, in almost all cases, *mezonot* items are considered the *ikkar* in a food mixture. The only time when this is not the case is when the *mezonot* is purely to hold the food together.

In this case, the pasta is clearly the *ikkar* food item and the bracha for kasha varnishkes is *mezonot* (and just *mezonot*).

All of this information can be found at Orach Chayim 212:1 and the Mishna Berurah and Biur Halacha there